# Image slide gallery with jquery, how to do this?

Tags: jquery, css, image, animation, slider

I'm trying to make a slider with jQuery and actually I do not know what's causing the error.

I'm pretty new at this language and I'm learning so yeah, my code might look stupid :D

Alright, so basically I have five images: 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5, and below is my code:

HTML:

```
<html>
...
<section id="image_slider">
    <div id="trapezoid"></div> <!-- I'll explain that div below :P -->
    
    <img class="image" id="img1" src="1.png" alt="1"></img>
    <img class="image" id="img2" src="2.png" alt="2"></img>
    <img class="image" id="img3" src="3.png" alt="3"></img>
    <img class="image" id="img4" src="4.png" alt="4"></img>
    <img class="image" id="img5" src="5.png" alt="5"></img>
    
    
    
 </section>
...
</html>
```

CSS:

```
<CSS>
#image_slider {
    height:500px;
    
    /*
    background-image: url("1.png");
    background-image: url("2.png");
    background-image: url("3.png");
    background-image: url("4.png");
    background-image: url("5.png");
    */
}

/* 
#trapezoid
{
    border-bottom: 500px solid #555;
    border-left: 0px solid transparent;
    border-right: 125px solid transparent;  
    height: 0;
    width: 500px;
    position:absolute;
}
*/
   
.image {
    vertical-align:top;
    position:absolute;
}
</CSS>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var i=0;
setTimeout(function(){
i++;
if(i=0)
{
$(".image").not("img1").hide();
}
else if(i=1)
{
$(".image").not("img2").hide();
}
else if(i=2)
{
$(".image").not("img3").hide();
}
else if(i=3)
{
$(".image").not("img4").hide();
}
else if(i=4)
{
$(".image").not("img5").hide();
}
else if(i=5)

{
i=-1;
}
}2000);
});
  </script>
```

Alright, so from the beginning: I'm considering two ways how I want slider to look like.

The first and original one, in that case I wanted to make a slider in which images will move from right to left, also i wanted to have a trapezoidal shape over this slider that's why there's a div with id="trapezoidal", but it seemed impossible to do when I had  images implemented in html document because images didn't wanted to permit this trapezoid to be over them all, when I implemented those images as background images in stylesheet, it kinda worked yes, but for me it was impossible to animate 5 background images so it would look nice.

So finally, please help me with jQuery code, to make that slider work in this way: every 5 seconds images are changing by sliding to the left. The old one is disappearing by moving to the left and the new one is appearing by moving to the left. (The new one shall be "behind" the old one).

Also please explain why my jQuery code isn't working, I mean I know there are loops in jQuery like while, for etc but they didn't work either, I do not know why the loop is not repeating every 2s...

Comment: setTimeOut is called only once. use setInterval.  You need to put a ',' before 2000. It's if(i == 4) NOT if(i = 4) And, your code is only making the images to be hidden... not shown. I think you need to learn the basics of javascript first and then try again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest version of code, switches and slides images. You can work on this and improve if you wish to.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            let intrvl = 3000;
            var i = 0;
            $(".image").hide();
            setInterval(function () {

                i++;
                $(".image").hide();
                $("#img" + i).show();

                $("#img" + i).css("left", "300px");
                $("#img" + i).animate(
                    {
                        "left": "0px"
                    }, intrvl);

                if (i >= 5) {
                    i = 0;
                }
            }, intrvl);

        });
```

```css
        .image {
            position: fixed
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="image_slider">
        <div id="trapezoid"></div> <!-- I'll explain that div below :P -->
        <img class="image" id="img1" height="200" src="images/1.jpg" alt="1" />
        <img class="image" id="img2" height="200" src="images/2.jpg" alt="2" />
        <img class="image" id="img3" height="200" src="images/3.jpg" alt="3" />
        <img class="image" id="img4" height="200" src="images/4.jpg" alt="4" />
        <img class="image" id="img5" height="200" src="images/5.jpg" alt="5" />
    </section>
```

Comment: Alright, I understood how this works, I redone your code a bit, so images are fading in and out in the same time. I have one last question. It will be separate comment.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so here the code of Alwaysa Learner which I have edited a bit:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
            let intrvl = 3000;
            var i = 0;
            var d = 1;
            $(".image").not("#img1").hide();
            setInterval(function () {
                
                i++;
                d++;
                $(".image").hide();
                $("#img" + i).show();
                
                    
                $("#img" + i).css("opacity", "1.0");
                $("#img" + i).animate(
                    {
                        "opacity": "0"
                    }, intrvl);
                $("#img" + d).show();   
                $("#img" + d).css("opacity", "0");
                $("#img" + d).animate(
                    {
                        "opacity": "1.0"
                    }, intrvl);
                

                if (i >= 5) {
                    i = 0;
                }
                if (d >=6) {
                    d = 1;
                    $(".image").hide();
                    $("#img5").show();
                
                    
                    $("#img5").css("opacity", "1.0");
                    $("#img5").animate(
                    {
                        "opacity": "0"
                    }, intrvl);
                    $("#img1").show();  
                    $("#img1").css("opacity", "0");
                    $("#img1").animate(
                    {
                        "opacity": "1.0"
                    }, intrvl);
                    
                }
                
            }, intrvl);

        });
  </script>
```

The slider itself works wonderfully. But I would like to try adding this trapezoidal shape over the changing images:

CSS:

```
#trapezoid {
border-bottom: 500px solid #555;
    border-left: 0px solid transparent;
    border-right: 125px solid transparent;
    height: 0;
    width: 500px;
}
```

The problem is that the images when their position is set to "position: fixed" they're showing up above the trapezoidal shape on which I would like to add paragraphs like "img1", "img2", "img3" etc.

I also tried setting position:absolute to trapezoidal shape and deleting position setting for class .image, but it didin't worked.

So my question is: Is it possible to make this trapezoidal shape showing above the images, when they're showing up & hiding thanks to jquery code above?
Or should I... dunno... add the trapezoid shape on images itself with GIMP for example? But It would affect the trapezoid and paragraph opacity in a negative way, wouldn't it?

Comment: can you include your html code and make a code snippet?